# Removing localStorage key depending on the row of the table (index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, local-storage

This is my ctrl:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($window, $scope) {

    $scope.initData = [
        {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",  
        },
        {
            firstName: "Jane",
            lastName: "Doe",
        },
        {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith",
        }
    ];

    $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
    $scope.retrievedData = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('initData'));
    console.log($scope.retrievedData);
    $scope.sortedType = 'firstName';
    $scope.sortedReverse = false;


    $scope.removeRow = function (row) {
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(row, 1);
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('initData');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'firstName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">First Name</span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'lastName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">Last Name</span>
                    </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in retrievedData | orderBy: sortedType: sortedReverse">
                <td>{{v.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{v.lastName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow();">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My `ng-controller` and `ng-app` is assigned in the html, so we need not to worry about that. What happens here with the `removeRow()` function is that I manage to delete the row, but I need it to delete it from `localStorage` as well. At this point, doing the `$window.localStorage.removeItem('initData');` is not an option, since it deletes entire object. How can I do this?

How can I delete the part of the `localStorage` that only contains the data that is removed with the row?

EDIT: I understand that I can't edit the key values, but how can I set the new ones? Placing the `$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));` in the function doesn't really help.

SOLUTIN: Thanks to the guys that answered. I've fixed it by adding: `$scope.initData.splice(row, 1);` below `$scope.retrievedData.splice(row, 1);` I've figured out that I've already been using the index in the `row` argument. After that I've wrote:  `$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));` Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to edit the contents of the localStorage value, only override it.

What you should do is edit `$scope.initData` and then use  `$window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));` to override it.

You need to add change the click to `ng-click="removeRow($index)"` (`$index` is the current repeated element index) then in the function 
   $scope.removeRow = function (rowIndex) {
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.retrievedData));
    }

since the u change the `retrievedData` before saving again to localstorage it will have the new value of the data -  i.e without the row.

Comment: How can I know which array  index has been removed?

Comment: send `$index` which is the row number to the removeRow function and then `splice(index,1)`